# Comfast CF-953AX is not work in Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, ubuntu-22.04

I recently bought a usb wifiless card. It's a Comfast CF-953AX card, which has a kernel driver.
[product info](https://github.com/morrownr/USB-WiFi/blob/main/home/USB_WiFi_Adapters_that_are_supported_with_Linux_in-kernel_drivers.md)

I use it on Ubuntu 22.04, which kernel is 5.15x hasn't this card driver. so I upgrade kernel version follow the guide from a blog.
[blog](https://www.medo64.com/2023/07/running-comfast-cf-953ax-on-ubuntu-22-04/)

It's seems ok, but I got a connection time out error when I try connect a wifi. It's a driver problem?

```
# uname -r
6.5.0-21-generic

# lsusb
Bus 004 Device 002: ID 0e8d:7961 MediaTek Inc. Wireless_Device

# sudo iw wlan1 info
Interface wlan1
    ifindex 9
    wdev 0x900000001
    addr e0:e1:a9:36:8b:4d
    type monitor
    wiphy 9
    txpower 3.00 dBm
    multicast TXQ:
        qsz-byt qsz-pkt flows   drops   marks   overlmt hashcol tx-bytes    tx-packets
        0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0       0

# sudo ip link set wlan1 up 
RTNETLINK answers: Connection timed out

# sudo dmesg
[ 1199.787191] mt7921u 4-2:1.3: Message 00020001 (seq 3) timeout
[ 1199.787239] ------------[ cut here ]------------
[ 1199.787243] WARNING: CPU: 2 PID: 3596 at net/mac80211/iface.c:1143 ieee80211_add_virtual_monitor+0x2b6/0x2e0 [mac80211]
[ 1199.787419] Modules linked in: tcp_diag inet_diag mt7921u mt7921_common mt76_connac_lib mt76_usb mt76 mac80211 libarc4 xt_nat xt_tcpudp veth xt_conntrack nft_chain_nat xt_MASQUERADE nf_nat nf_conntrack_netlink nf_conntrack nf_defrag_ipv6 nf_defrag_ipv4 xfrm_user xfrm_algo xt_addrtype nft_compat nf_tables nfnetlink br_netfilter bridge stp llc overlay btusb btrtl btbcm btintel btmtk bluetooth ecdh_generic ecc apple_mfi_fastcharge joydev input_leds binfmt_misc nls_iso8859_1 snd_hda_codec_hdmi intel_rapl_msr intel_rapl_common snd_hda_codec_cirrus snd_hda_codec_generic x86_pkg_temp_thermal intel_powerclamp ledtrig_audio mei_hdcp mei_pxp coretemp snd_hda_intel kvm_intel snd_intel_dspcfg snd_intel_sdw_acpi kvm snd_hda_codec wl(POE) applesmc snd_hda_core irqbypass snd_hwdep snd_pcm mei_me snd_timer rapl snd mei cfg80211 apple_gmux soundcore intel_cstate mac_hid at24 sch_fq_codel dm_multipath scsi_dh_rdac scsi_dh_emc scsi_dh_alua msr efi_pstore ip_tables x_tables autofs4 btrfs blake2b_generic raid10 raid456 async_raid6_recov
[ 1199.787519]  async_memcpy async_pq async_xor async_tx xor raid6_pq libcrc32c raid1 raid0 multipath linear i915 crct10dif_pclmul crc32_pclmul hid_appleir drm_buddy polyval_clmulni hid_generic i2c_algo_bit ttm polyval_generic drm_display_helper ghash_clmulni_intel cec aesni_intel rc_core drm_kms_helper crypto_simd firewire_ohci usbhid ahci sdhci_pci hid cqhci firewire_core cryptd thunderbolt libahci lpc_ich xhci_pci tg3 crc_itu_t i2c_i801 drm sdhci i2c_smbus xhci_pci_renesas video wmi [last unloaded: libarc4]
[ 1199.787584] CPU: 2 PID: 3596 Comm: ip Tainted: P        W  OE      6.5.0-21-generic #21~22.04.1-Ubuntu
[ 1199.787589] Hardware name: Apple Inc. Macmini6,1/Mac-031AEE4D24BFF0B1, BIOS 286.0.0.0.0 06/10/2020
[ 1199.787591] RIP: 0010:ieee80211_add_virtual_monitor+0x2b6/0x2e0 [mac80211]
[ 1199.787732] Code: 00 00 e8 dd 46 6a c6 e8 f8 e6 37 c6 4c 89 e6 48 89 df e8 7d f4 fd ff 4c 89 e7 e8 b5 a5 94 c5 8b 45 d4 e9 97 fd ff ff 89 45 d4 <0f> 0b 4c 89 e7 e8 a0 a5 94 c5 8b 45 d4 e9 82 fd ff ff b8 f4 ff ff
[ 1199.787736] RSP: 0018:ffffb185017a7668 EFLAGS: 00010282
[ 1199.787740] RAX: 00000000ffffff92 RBX: ffff8b1bd3d30900 RCX: 0000000000000000
[ 1199.787742] RDX: 0000000000000000 RSI: 0000000000000000 RDI: 0000000000000000
[ 1199.787744] RBP: ffffb185017a76a0 R08: 0000000000000000 R09: 0000000000000000
[ 1199.787746] R10: 0000000000000000 R11: 0000000000000000 R12: ffff8b1bd221a000
[ 1199.787748] R13: ffff8b1bd221a058 R14: ffff8b1bd221af30 R15: ffff8b1bdb2cc000
[ 1199.787750] FS:  00007f9acb387b80(0000) GS:ffff8b1d27300000(0000) knlGS:0000000000000000
[ 1199.787753] CS:  0010 DS: 0000 ES: 0000 CR0: 0000000080050033
[ 1199.787755] CR2: 000055aa033b8ee0 CR3: 0000000100848005 CR4: 00000000001706e0
[ 1199.787758] Call Trace:
[ 1199.787761]  <TASK>
[ 1199.787765]  ? show_regs+0x6d/0x80
[ 1199.787773]  ? __warn+0x89/0x160
[ 1199.787780]  ? ieee80211_add_virtual_monitor+0x2b6/0x2e0 [mac80211]
[ 1199.787922]  ? report_bug+0x17e/0x1b0
[ 1199.787929]  ? handle_bug+0x46/0x90
[ 1199.787935]  ? exc_invalid_op+0x18/0x80
[ 1199.787939]  ? asm_exc_invalid_op+0x1b/0x20
[ 1199.787947]  ? ieee80211_add_virtual_monitor+0x2b6/0x2e0 [mac80211]
[ 1199.788078]  ? ieee80211_add_virtual_monitor+0x11f/0x2e0 [mac80211]
[ 1199.788211]  ? mt7921_start+0x5f/0x70 [mt7921_common]
[ 1199.788228]  ieee80211_do_open+0x7a4/0x7e0 [mac80211]
[ 1199.788345]  ieee80211_open+0x76/0xa0 [mac80211]
[ 1199.788436]  __dev_open+0x105/0x1d0
[ 1199.788441]  __dev_change_flags+0x1b5/0x230
[ 1199.788445]  dev_change_flags+0x27/0x80
[ 1199.788449]  do_setlink+0x3cb/0xe80
[ 1199.788454]  ? __nla_validate_parse+0x49/0x1e0
[ 1199.788459]  __rtnl_newlink+0x6e5/0x770
[ 1199.788465]  rtnl_newlink+0x48/0x80
[ 1199.788468]  rtnetlink_rcv_msg+0x170/0x430
[ 1199.788472]  ? copyout+0x25/0x50
[ 1199.788477]  ? __pfx_rtnetlink_rcv_msg+0x10/0x10
[ 1199.788480]  netlink_rcv_skb+0x5d/0x110
[ 1199.788488]  rtnetlink_rcv+0x15/0x30
[ 1199.788493]  netlink_unicast+0x1b3/0x2a0
[ 1199.788498]  netlink_sendmsg+0x25e/0x4e0
[ 1199.788504]  ____sys_sendmsg+0x3ef/0x420
[ 1199.788511]  ___sys_sendmsg+0x9a/0xf0
[ 1199.788518]  __sys_sendmsg+0x89/0xf0
[ 1199.788524]  __x64_sys_sendmsg+0x1d/0x30
[ 1199.788527]  do_syscall_64+0x5b/0x90
[ 1199.788532]  ? do_user_addr_fault+0x17a/0x6b0
[ 1199.788536]  ? exit_to_user_mode_prepare+0x30/0xb0
[ 1199.788539]  ? irqentry_exit_to_user_mode+0x17/0x20
[ 1199.788544]  ? irqentry_exit+0x43/0x50
[ 1199.788548]  ? exc_page_fault+0x94/0x1b0
[ 1199.788553]  entry_SYSCALL_64_after_hwframe+0x6e/0xd8
[ 1199.788558] RIP: 0033:0x7f9acb127967
[ 1199.788584] Code: 0f 00 f7 d8 64 89 02 48 c7 c0 ff ff ff ff eb b9 0f 1f 00 f3 0f 1e fa 64 8b 04 25 18 00 00 00 85 c0 75 10 b8 2e 00 00 00 0f 05 <48> 3d 00 f0 ff ff 77 51 c3 48 83 ec 28 89 54 24 1c 48 89 74 24 10
[ 1199.788587] RSP: 002b:00007fff20301558 EFLAGS: 00000246 ORIG_RAX: 000000000000002e
[ 1199.788591] RAX: ffffffffffffffda RBX: 0000000065d8a9cc RCX: 00007f9acb127967
[ 1199.788593] RDX: 0000000000000000 RSI: 00007fff203015c0 RDI: 0000000000000003
[ 1199.788595] RBP: 0000000000000000 R08: 0000000000000001 R09: 000055aa0368b2b0
[ 1199.788597] R10: 0000000000000078 R11: 0000000000000246 R12: 0000000000000001
[ 1199.788599] R13: 00007fff20301670 R14: 0000000000000000 R15: 000055aa0336f040
[ 1199.788603]  </TASK>
[ 1199.788604] ---[ end trace 0000000000000000 ]---
[ 1199.948033] mt7921u 4-2:1.3: HW/SW Version: 0x8a108a10, Build Time: 20211108213239a

[ 1199.966017] mt7921u 4-2:1.3: WM Firmware Version: ____000000, Build Time: 20211108213319
```

Answer (score 0):

I've solved this problem. I follow the guide from [here](https://github.com/morrownr/USB-WiFi/blob/main/home/How_to_Install_Firmware_for_Mediatek_based_USB_WiFi_adapters.md), download the newest version of firmware and replace it, and it works on.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).